Running playbook on specific host with extra-vars
I'm trying to improve an Ansible inventory and I've made this inventory:
test_inventory.yml:
############### Inventaire Test##############
envtest:
    hosts:
        toto:
            java_version: 8
            si: si1
            type: oracle
            ip: xxx
        tata:
            java_version: 8
            si: si2
            type: postgres
            ip: xxx
        tato:
            java_version: 8
            si: si3
            type: jboss
            gnl: coeur_sint
            ip: xx

I've written a test playbook (I know it will fail, but just to check if the right host are called):
################## Playbook de Test ##################
---
  - name: juste pour tester
    hosts: "{{ hosts }}"
    gather_facts: false
    tasks:
        - debug:
            msg: "test"

Then I launch the playbook like this:
ansible-playbook -i test_inventory.yml test.yml --extra-vars "hosts=envtest:*:*:rgcu"
But it return all my host in the console..:
PLAY [juste pour tester] ***************

TASK [debug] *************************
ok: [tata] => {
    "msg": "test"
}
ok: [tato] => {
    "msg": "test"
}
ok: [toto] => {
    "msg": "test"


How can I filter in extra-vars to target for example on host with si=si2?

The real question is why would you want to do this while Ansible has the built-in feature specifically for that - Patterns: targeting hosts and groups.
The idea is that you can leave your playbook with hosts: envtest or even hosts: all (if you're sure that this playbook won't be used with other random invetories). If you need to run the playbook only against some of the hosts, you just use the standard --limit flag:
ansible-playbook test.yml -i test_inventory.yml --limit tata

The Patterns and ansible-playbook flags section covers more details on this.
To answer a more specific question on host filtering - you can use different approaches.
If you need to perform just a task or a block of tasks if si variable equals to si2, you can use a when condition:
---
- name: juste pour tester
  hosts: envtest
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "test"
      when: si == "si2"

Alternatively, if you need to run the whole plays on the hosts like this or if there are many of them, you can define another group dynamically with add_host module:
---
- name: Define the group dynamically
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Loop over the envtest group to add the hosts to a custom group based on the variable name
      add_host:
        group: custom_group
        name: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ groups['envtest'] }}"
      when: hostvars[item] == "si2"

- name: just pour tester
  hosts: custom_group
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
     - debug:
         msg: "test"

You can parametrize that, defining the criteria with --extra-vars (but remember to either define a default value if the extra vars haven't been set, or assert their existence before their use):
      when: hostvars[item] == custom_criteria | default("si2")


Not sure what you are trying to achieve here but I wouldn't use --extra-vars to do host filtering on your playbook.
If you want to filter hosts at the play level the recommended way would be to use --limit / -l
ansible-playbook -l s1_hosts -i test_inventory.yml test.yml

You can create sub groups to filter by specific attribute
envtest:
    children:
      s1_hosts:
        toto:
    hosts:
        toto:
            java_version: 8
            si: si1
            type: oracle
            ip: xxx
        tata:
            java_version: 8
            si: si2
            type: postgres
            ip: xxx
        tato:
            java_version: 8
            si: si3
            type: jboss
            gnl: coeur_sint
            ip: xx



"Not sure what you are trying to achieve here" - I think I understood the OP's intention, I've edited my answer accordingly.

